# Different things returned based on a requested param with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wonder if there's a possibility for a method to return different things based on what param was requested. An example:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String templateForName = "Hello, %s!";
private static final String templateForTest = "Testing new output, which is %s!";

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name
                        ,@RequestParam(value="test", defaultValue="TEST value") String test
                        ) {
                //An if here that would decide which param was requested?
                return new Greeting(String.format(templateForName, name));

}
```

This here would display, for example, "Hello, User!" if requested with `?name=User`
Is it possible to display "Testing new output, which is test!" is requested with `?test=test`

I am only just starting doing anything with Spring, so if something is unclear or information provided is insufficient, do let me know and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Why not just make the parameters part of a PATH parameter if they are always going to have different, well-defined behavior?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean, could you provide an example please?

Comment: Sure I will add an answer with an example when I have some time today

Comment: I think you should use just one RequestParam, and have an if statement to check for the test value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the `if else conditions` to return the proper greeting object as below:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name
                            ,@RequestParam(value="test", defaultValue="TEST value") String test
                            ) {
         Greeting greeting = null;
        if(name.equals("User")) {
             greeting = new Greeting(String.format(templateForName, name));
        } else if(test.equals("test"))  {
              greeting = new Greeting(String.format(templateForTest, test));
        }
        return greeting;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! And do you perhaps know if it's possible to do using two different `@RequestMapping` that use the same method of `public returnType greeting`? Or perhaps selection from `Map<>`, if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, using PATH params:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting/name/{name}")
public Greeting nameGreeting(@PathParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

    return new Greeting(String.format(templateForName, name));

}

@RequestMapping("/greeting/test/{test}")
public Greeting testGreeting(@PathParam(value="test", defaultValue="TEST value") String name) {

    return new Greeting(String.format(templateForTest, test));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one @RequestParam and test for the value you're looking for.

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    if(name.equals("Test")) {
         return new Greeting(String.format(templateForTest, test));
    } 
    return new Greeting(String.format(templateForName, name));
}
```